# Parsley.js: Error Message Hierarchy

Tags: error-handling, validation, parsley.js

I am new to Parsley, and want to provide a good UX for my end users. The example on the Parsley site is admittedly "not a perfect example of UX-awareness."  Which leaves me wishing that there was a good example of error message display hierarchy.

The user should never see multiple error messages for the same field; it should only ever be one at a time. So, how do I make that happen?

I would suggest structuring the hierarchy according to the order in which the constraints are applied to the field.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. Check out: [parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#parsleyclasses](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#parsleyclasses)
   and use code from "Change error container" section.
2. Add this to your CSS: `.parsley-container{display:none} input:focus+.parsley-container{display:block}`

I made something more for myself:

```
.parsley-container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #888888;
}
.parsley-container:after, .parsley-container:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.parsley-container:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.parsley-container:before {
  border-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #888888;
  border-width: 11px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -11px;
}
input:focus + .parsley-container,
input:active + .parsley-container {
  display: block;
}
```

Pretty much like Chrome HTML5 validation.

Answer (score 0):

The addValidator() function accepts a priority value as the third parameter.  The default for built-in validators is 30 for most of them, except "notblank" is 2, "regexp" is 64, "type-xxx" is 256 and "required" is 512. Parsley stops validating on the highest priority failing test(s).  This is configurable with the `priorityEnabled` setting.  In order to get just one at a time you can create custom validators each with a different priority:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('check3', function(val, req) {
    return (val == whatever3(val, req));
// +--- Higher than check2
// v
}, 103).addMessage('en', 'check3', 'Failed check 3');

window.Parsley.addValidator('check2', function(val, req) {
    return (val == whatever2(val, req));
// +--- Higher than check1
// v
}, 102).addMessage('en', 'check2', 'Failed check 2');

window.Parsley.addValidator('check1', function(val, req) {
    return (val == whatever1(val, req));
// +--- Higher than many, lower than "required (512)" and "type-xxx (256)"
// v
}, 101).addMessage('en', 'check1', 'Failed check 1');
```